# Jeditable returns entire HTML document instead of new text

Tags: html, jeditable

SCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{SITEURL}includes/jquery.jeditable.js"  charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function() {
             $(".edit").editable("window.location.href", { 
                indicator : "<img src='img/indicator.gif'>",
                tooltip   : "Doubleclick to edit...",
                event     : "dblclick",
                style  : "inherit"
            });
            });
    </script>
```

HTML

```
<p class="cost float-right edit"">10000</p>
```

I don't think there is anything wrong with what I'm doing.. only that I'm kinda using an unknown framework developed by my senior... the plugin is working great.. only that its returning the entire document after submitting of the form

Answer (score 0):

Your saving script should return the string you want to display on the page. Now you are returning html for the full page.